# Start a Testcontainers container during each fresh application context (@DirtiesContext), with injection of properties (@DynamicPropertySource)

Tags: spring, junit4, cucumber-java, testcontainers, cucumber-junit

I am using Testcontainers to execute integration tests in a Spring project. I am using JUnit 4.x and Cucumber 7.4.1.

I want to start a `docker-compose.yml`-based set of containers before each test, as that makes it easy to start from scratch. Hence, I am using `@DirtiesContext`.

The challenge here is that certain application properties, such as `spring.rabbitmq.host`, are needed before the actual application context can start. So I need to inject them beforehand. There is `@DynamicPropertySource` for that. But then I also need to get access to my context-scoped docker containers. The best I came up with so far is the following:

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class CucumberITConfig {
    @DynamicPropertySource
    private static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        DockerComposeContainer container = new DockerComposeContainer(new File("docker-compose.yml"))
                .withExposedService("rabbitmq", 5672);

        container.start();
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.host", () -> container.getServiceHost("rabbitmq", 5672));
    }
}
```

This constructs new docker containers locally and waits for the host to be passed to the registry. While this seem to work, this looks more like a hackish approach to me. Also, a problem here is that the containers stack up after each test. That is, in the 7th test, for example, the containers from all previous 6 cycles are still running.

Are there better approaches to start Testcontainers-based docker containers before each application context, while also being able to destruct them afterwards?

Comment: You may have some more luck if you try asking this question as a JUnit 5 + Spring Boot question. The solution would be the same but you'd have a larger audience

Comment: What you're doing is going to be slow wrote a blog post about making it faster, can't copy paste it right now https://logarithmicwhale.com/posts/faster-tests-by-resuing-testcontainers-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@DirtiesContext` after all, you can set these values as System properties and omit `@DynamicPropertySource` altogether. However, as others have pointed out, solving test pollution by re-creating the Spring context and all dependent services for every test class will be very slow and is generally considered an anti-pattern.